# Find Parent based on children- Xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an Xml having two main elements named "Pattern" and "Members"

```
<Root>
    <Pattern name="A">
        <Member id="2" />
        <Member id="3" />
        <Member id="6" />
        <Member id="20" />
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern name="B">
        <Member id="3" />
        <Member id="4" />
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern name="C">
        <Member id="11" />
        <Member id="13" />
        <Member id="14" />
    </Pattern>
    <Members>
        <Member id="1" name="Member1" >
            <Member id="2" name="Member2" >
                <Member id="3" name="Member3" />
                <Member id="4" name="Member4" />
            </Member>
            <Member id="5" name="Member5" >
                <Member id="6" name="Member6" />
                <Member id="7" name="Member7" />
            </Member>
            <Member id="8" name="Member8" >
                <Member id="9" name="Member9" />
            </Member>
            <Member id="10" name="Member10" >
                <Member id="11" name="Member11" />
            </Member>
            <Member id="12" name="Member12" >
                <Member id="13" name="Member13" />
                <Member id="14" name="Member14" >
                    <Member id="15" name="Member15" />
                    <Member id="16" name="Member16" >
                        <Member id="17" name="Member17" >
                            <Member id="18" name="Member18" />
                            <Member id="19" name="Member19" />
                            <Member id="20" name="Member20" />
                        </Member>
                    </Member>
                </Member>
            </Member>
        </Member>
    </Members>
</Root>
```

the above example has 3 Patterns
Its having an element named "Member". Based on the id, need to find the root element from "Members". Suppose in the Pattern B, Member id=3 and id=4 are the exact children of member2(id=2). if all the ids matches with the children, its immediate parent has to be displayed in the output. the expected output is

```
<output>
    <Pattern name="A">
        <Member id="2"/>
        <Member id="3"/>
        <Member id="6"/>
        <Member id="20"/>
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern name="B">
        <Member id="2"/>
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern name="C">
        <Member id="10"/>
        <Member id="12"/>
    </Pattern>
</output>
```

Pattern A:
the members in Pattern A are not containing full child members so no change in output:

```
<Pattern name="A">
    <Member id="2"/>
    <Member id="3"/>
    <Member id="6"/>
    <Member id="20"/>
</Pattern>
```

Pattern B:
these are exact child members of id 2
so the output contains

```
<Pattern name="B">
    <Member id="2"/>
</Pattern>
```

Pattern C:

member id="11" is the child member of Member id="10"(all child for member id=10)
member id=12 contains 2 child members id =13 and id=14. these exists.
so the output for Pattern C is

```
<Pattern name="C">
        <Member id="10"/>
        <Member id="12"/>
    </Pattern>
```

Can anyone please help me on this output in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: I have read and re-read your post, and I still can't understand what you need.  In addition, I cannot understand how your post relates to your title -- you do not appear to be looking at parents and children at all, but rather at separate but (somewhat) parallel node trees.  Please clarify your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you.  Let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <!-- Get the parent id of every member. -->
  <xsl:variable name="parents">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Members//Member" mode="parents"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="parentList" select="msxml:node-set($parents)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="output">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Process each pattern. -->
  <xsl:template match="Pattern">
    <!-- Get the parent ids of the Members in this pattern.  -->
    <xsl:variable name="patternParentIDs">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$parentList/Member[id = current()/Member/@id]/parentid"/>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:variable name="patternParentIDList" select="msxml:node-set($patternParentIDs)"/>

    <!-- Get a distinct list of patternParentIDs. -->
    <xsl:variable name="distinctParents">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$patternParentIDList/parentid[not(. = preceding-sibling::parentid)]"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="distinctParentList" select="msxml:node-set($distinctParents)"/>

    <!-- Determine of each parent id has all members included. -->
    <xsl:variable name="allMembers">
      <xsl:for-each select="$distinctParentList/parentid">
        <xsl:variable name="parentid" select="."/>

        <xsl:if test="count($parentList/Member[parentid=$parentid]) != count($patternParentIDList/parentid[.=$parentid])">
          <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($allMembers)=0">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="$distinctParentList/parentid">
            <xsl:element name="Member">
              <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- Suppress the Members. -->
  <xsl:template match="Members"/>

  <!-- parents mode.  -->
  <xsl:template match="Member" mode="parents">
    <Member>
      <id>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </id>
      <parentid>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@id"/>
      </parentid>
    </Member>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```