# Remove child node based on parent node

Tags: xslt

The below sample Xml has 2 different sets, One is "**Pattern**" and one more is "**Members**". **Pattern** is a sub set of **Members**.

```
<Root>
    <Pattern name="A">
        <Member id="2" />
        <Member id="4"/>
        <Member id="10"/>
        <Member id="11"/>
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern name="B">
        <Member id="3" />
        <Member id="4"/>
        <Member id="10"/>
        <Member id="11"/>
        <Member id="12"/>
        <Member id="13"/>
    </Pattern>
    <Members>
        <Member id="1" name="Member1">
            <Member id="2" name="Member2">
                <Member id="3" name="Member3"/>
                <Member id="4" name="Member4"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="5" name="Member5">
                <Member id="6" name="Member6"/>
                <Member id="7" name="Member7"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="8" name="Member8">
                <Member id="9" name="Member9"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="10" name="Member10">
                <Member id="11" name="Member11"/>
            </Member>
            <Member id="12" name="Member12">
                <Member id="13" name="Member13"/>
                <Member id="14" name="Member14">
                    <Member id="15" name="Member15"/>
                    <Member id="16" name="Member16">
                        <Member id="17" name="Member17">
                            <Member id="18" name="Member18"/>
                            <Member id="19" name="Member19"/>
                            <Member id="20" name="Member20"/>
                        </Member>
                    </Member>
                </Member>
            </Member>
        </Member>
    </Members>
</Root>
```

I need to remove Child node entry from **Pattern** comparing its attribute id with attribute id of Members when there is both parent and its child exists.

the expected output for the above is

```
<Output>
<Pattern name="A">
        <Member id="2" />       
        <Member id="10"/>
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern name="B">
        <Member id="3" />
        <Member id="4"/>
        <Member id="10"/>
        <Member id="12"/>
    </Pattern>
</Output>
```

Pattern A:
Out of 4 members, Member 4 is a child of Member 2. hence Member 4 has to be removed. Member 11 is a child of Member 10. So Member 11 has to delete.

Same logic for other patterns.

Help me on this in achieving in xslt 1.0.

thanks

Comment: Please paste the code you have tried so far

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352704/find-parent-based-on-children-xslt-1-0 In any case, it's just as unclear as the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a key to look-up the `Member` elements by their id

```
<xsl:key name="members" match="Members//Member" use="@id" />
```

Then, for a given `Pattern/Member` element, you can get the parent id like so

```
<xsl:variable name="parentId" select="key('members', @id)/parent::*/@id" />
```

You can then test whether the current `Member` needs to be copied to the output like so

```
<xsl:if test="not(../Member/@id = $parentId)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:if>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="members" match="Members//Member" use="@id" />

    <xsl:template match="Pattern/Member">
      <xsl:variable name="parentId" select="key('members', @id)/parent::*/@id" />
      <xsl:if test="not(../Member/@id = $parentId)">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Members" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually, you could reverse the logic, and instead perform a check on `Member` elements you don't want copied.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="members" match="Members//Member" use="@id" />

    <xsl:template match="Pattern/Member[../Member/@id = key('members', @id)/parent::*/@id]" />

    <xsl:template match="Members" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```